# Is there a way to view usages of a referenced jar (library) in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I just inherited a project I did not write so I'm trying to really learn how it works. It includes a lot of jars in the `libs` folder and I would like to investigate why many of them are there, or if they are necessary.

I am new to IntelliJ IDEA (although I am very familiar with Android Studio if that draws any parallels or is worth mentioning). Is there a way to check and see if a jar is used in the project, or see where its usages are? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to the sources? Is that a Maven project? What does the structure of the project look like? Please provide more details.

Comment: I don't have access to the sources. IntelliJ does it's best to show methods present in the jars but cannot completely decompile them. It is not a Maven project.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the jar from the classpath and see what breaks. You will very quickly find where that jar is used, and if it is necessary!

Comment: You mean just remove from my lib directory? I suppose I was hoping for a prettier way to show usages, but if that's not possible I can snoop around and remove some jars.